# Preventing edit conflict in Django's list_editable with multiple users

Tags: django, listview, django-admin

I'd like to use Django's list_editable feature to allow admins of my site to quickly update a whole bunch of items at once, or even just to quickly update a single item. However, there are multiple admins on this site.

My main concern: What happens if one admin edits record A (B, C) while another admin edits record D (E, F), on the same page, from different computers? Is the information for all visible records submitted when each user clicks "Save", or are just the modified records submitted? In other words, will the second submitter override the first submitter's data, even though they were editing different records?

Less of a problem, and a problem I can live with: what happens if both users edit the same record? I assume that the second submission will override the first, even if Django has something in place to address my main concern, but it would be nice if Django somehow prevents mistakes here, too.

Comment: on 1.4, the entire set is modified, not just the modified instances so yes, whoever saves last will set the state...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django has no internal anti-collision system. But you can use [django-reversion](https://github.com/etianen/django-reversion) or hack into admin's [get_changelist_forms](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/options.py#L492) and [saving forms](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/options.py#L1188) to manually merge changes of different users (or change form validation to fail if object is not the same, for example).