# Adding a custom validation to Django's auth_user in admin on list_editable

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

Django has `list_editable`. I need to edit `is_active` flag.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from django.contrib import admin
from django.db.models import Q
from django import forms

class MyUserAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User

    #def clean_is_active(self):
        # do something that validates your data
    #    print ' I am here... '
    #    print self.cleaned_data
    #    print self
    def clean(self):
        k = 1


class MyUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    list_display = ["id", "username", "email", "is_staff", "is_superuser", "is_active", "date_joined"]
    search_fields = ["username", "email"]
    list_display_links = ["id", "username"]
    list_editable = ("is_active",)
    list_per_page = 50

    form = MyUserAdminForm


# Had to unregister the User so it could be registered with MyUserAdmin
admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, MyUserAdmin)
```

I put this in `admin.py`, and I've registered my `admin.ModelAdmin` code. The display is fine. So `MyUserAdmin` is working fine.

This code should fail because of the clean method. But it didn't. It isn't using `MyUserAdminForm` apparently. I need to clean the is_active.

Thanks.

---

Note I have inherited from `admin.ModelAdmin` rather than `UsreAdmin`. I have used all the combinations I can have......

---

Update

I think this piece of code is only useful for the edit page, not for the `list_editable` option.

Comment: `clean_is_active` doesn't have to return `self.cleaned_data["is_active"]`. Did you watch the console? Do you get an "I am here..." message there? Cause clean methods doesn't have to return nothing. They just need to raise a `ValidationError` if they find some inconsistence in the object you are saving

Comment: @marianobianchi Thank you. you are right, i confused myself with `clean`. But anyhow. No, I didn't see any print statement in my console. That's the weird part :( I've even implemented a clean method that just said `k = 1`, and it still able to change the flag!!! This means Django is not picking up my custom class :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe the problem is that you should inherit your custom `MyUserAdmin` from `UserAdmin` from django's admin models...

Here you can find an example of how to do that: [Customizing an Admin form in Django while also using autodiscover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/471550/customizing-an-admin-form-in-django-while-also-using-autodiscover)

When you add a change like this, you should restart your server (restart manage.py or apache or whatever you are using)

Comment: Thanks. Initially I have `UserAdmin` actually. But it didn't work. I changed it to `admin.ModelAdmin`. In any case, I've attached the full code. BUt none of the options can solve my problem. So weird. By default, in urls.py there is the `autodiscover` already. I purposely setup a new 1.4 just to test this out.

Comment: Ah. I think the method is overriding the edit page. In other words, you have click on the editpage to see the effect of my fail code. So it doesn't trigger if you are on the list view page.

Comment: Ohh, i see your problem now. I didn't know you were using the list view to edit records of your database. Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10524794/preventing-edit-conflict-in-djangos-list-editable-with-multiple-users) can help you.